# How to group different entities, groups and sub-groups having common entity?

Tags: grouped-list

I am facing a hard time having design decision for below case. I am creating wireframe for a patient app. The platform is windows phone and surface (tablet). The nurse (user) needs to prescribe medications for patients. It can be taken at different times during the day also before or after meal. In order to depict this I have designed following wireframe.

Which of the below option is the perfect choice? (If no, whats the other options?) Appreciate pros and cons for the designs provided.

Note: The nurse also has the option to edit the medication and can view the app from different devices (win phone or surface only)

[image]

Comment: I would avoid B. From what I have seen from health care professionals, they first decide which medication to prescribe, and after that how to space it for the day. They don't go around thinking "what does the patient need after breakfast? a Loremepsom is good. And after dinner? Metformin. Oh, and another capsule of Lorempsom." It is more of a "The patient has X, so we will give Lorempsom for that. How much? 1200 mg per day should be enough. The serum levels will be high enough if we make it twice daily. And it irritates the stomach, so make it after food". But check my assumption with users.

Comment: Great point @RumiP. but then this option B seems good solution for Patient app .. where patient will be able to see daily dosages (as per their mental model) but then with same app, different viewers (users or lets say persona) are viewing same information in different format (information grouping).. so will this hamper consistency?

Comment: In my experience the timing of meds is actually given in requirement sheet, so doctors/patients don't have that much freedom about it.

Answer (score 1):

Can the same drug be prescribed to be taken before and after a meal? I have never seen that personally, but have no experience in the field except as a patient.

```
Medication   Breakfast     Lunch       Dinner
-----------+-----------+-----------+------------
Loremepson   >   after       —       before   <
```

Answer (score 0):

For option A, my brain has a hard time making sense of the information because the check boxes group together in a confusing way ([gestalt laws of grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping)). 
[image]

For option B, I agree with Rumi P.

Option C seems to be the best, but I can't help thinking it is missing some information. Especially for a grid that is editable, I would imagine there should be some sort of totals column for the total dosage of each medication type. In all your examples, a check in the wrong box might not be noticed by the user entering it, but the information could be blindly followed resulting in a medical mistake. In this use case some form of double checking is necessary. "Why does it say 5 times a day for this med? Oh, I meant to click the other box!"

Answer (score 0):

I like option B the most, both visually and for the organisation.

For a patient with an intensive program of medicaments intake this works the best. Meals are a key factor here, and nurse (or patient) has a sheet from the doctor when to give/take what, so they prepare pills in batches for each meal. So if you are getting ready for your lunch intake, option B is the quickest to get you the information which pills belong to this meal (and which boxes to organise together).

Everything else is too much of visual hunt for the type of meal.

By the way, I wouldn't understand abbreviations in option C at all without some elaborate context.